# ServiceMix and clustering

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-servicemix

First of all I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896074/how-do-i-cluster-servicemix) post and it partially answered my question but here's my dilemma: I'd like to install ServiceMix on two different machines, and I want them to be working on failover. Which means if one instance dies for whatever reason the other one takes over control, and if I have to install a third instance of ServiceMix it would be easy to do so.

What I'm planning on installing and using is basically : Camel (with Jetty extension), ActiveMQ, Karaf, hawt.io and webconsole.

So basically what I want to do is to have the same bundles in both OSGis, same configuration for both instances, when I change something on one it gets propagated to the second.

Any Idea on how I could get that done? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to experiment a bit, but I think it is a reachable task. 
First of all for the propagation Task you'll need to use the Apache Karaf Cellar clustering solution, it will help you propagate all your changes throughout your Cluster-Group. Second you'll need to configure a fail-over mechanism as described in [the documentation](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/failover.html). For this you most likely need to switch to Container-level locking. The crucial part is to make sure all your own bundles aren't stopped while the Karaf Cellar ones are already working. You might need to tweak the startlevels for your own apps and the default startlevel a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just a Cellar-related question though, after I install ServiceMix on different machines, how do I connect them using Cellar and how do I define which is the master and which is/are the slaves?

Comment: Regarding Cellar itself you can't, cellar does use Hazelcast with mulitcast and it will synchronize all nodes. A Master/Slave mechanism isn't provided. For Failover you'll need to combine it with the outlined solution.